# Binding angular with an existing data model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm looking at html data binding and templating alternatives to apply to an existing model-driven system. I promise I'll get to the Angular question below, but it will have little meaning without some context. The data has the following properties:

- The JavaScript classes in the system reflect a fact model (Object-Role Model) that describes the system, including arbitrary derivation rules formally described in the model and evaluated client side. There is a lightweight framework to allow declarative declarations of the fact system with minimal code.
- All of the data management (declarative client model and rules, JSON communication, data access layer, database) is generated from the same model.
- All change communication (inlcuding initial load) is done in terms of 'change sets' describe in terms of objects and facts from the model. Change sets can coexist and can be large (all changes made since the page loaded) or small (a single user action tracked in an undo/redo stack)
- The client model is a fully navigable graph structure with real objects (not untyped JSON blobs). The structure is designed to be read using standard JavaScript, but all writes to the system are done through a standard API based on the model elements.

Although I'm using it for standard apps (where I'm interested in the data binding aspects), the system was originally designed for client-side graphical editing of data models, including all usual editing capabilities (live validation, undo/redo, etc.). The apps can run 100% client side, and the data models can be quite large.

In this scenario, the normal Angular approach of two-way data binding that updates scope data based on DOM changes (and vice-versa) is simply too simplistic and violates numerous assumptions underlying the heavily controlled data model.

- The UI controls may not directly change data. Instead, a control change triggers a named 'command' in the system. Each command is run under tracking code that makes one or more changes to the data (through the framework API) and runs all applicable derivations in the system. A successful change produces an undo unit, a failed change rolls back automatically.
- Changes to the system are cleanly packaged into change objects that correspond to the change triggered by a command (including the input data and any derived changes). I do not need a data binding system to watch changes to the model itself, just a way to feed it change sets.

**Now to the angular question:**
I may be completely on the wrong track, but I'm assuming I need to tackle $watch, $apply, and $digest functionality using some sort of customized scope object to allow Angular to consume and update apps with this data model. I'm looking for some sort of function-based approach that allows the binding to do something other than direct field access.

I'm sure I'm not the only one who has wanted to integrate existing mature data structures into the Angular system, and I'm assuming that an MVC can actually detach its data from its view as the pattern name advertises, but I haven't found any documented samples that do this. Any pointers would be much appreciated. Thank you.